# Missing rows in MySQL /InnoDB

Tags: php, mysql, count, innodb

I have a website in PHP/MySQL, hosted on a public server. The website is used to host data on tests we do. Each test in inserted in the database and the testID (primary) is auto incremented. As of today we have about 1100 tests/rows.

A few days ago I came across a weird error, the database only displays 699 rows. And according to the Db the last entry was in August last year. This is off course wrong.

I can INSERT new rows via the webpage, and it is assigned a new auto incremented ID, and all data is displayed well. Last I checked we have reached testID 1037, but according to cPanel/phpmyadmin there are only 699 rows, even if I add 10 more rows. Seems like I have reached some kind of limit.

I know that InnoDB has some issue when using COUNT(*), but I should be able to SELECT a certain testID >699 when I know it's there!

Tech Support tried implementing this on my server ($cfg['MaxExactCount'] = 200000;), but didn't do the trick.

I have no joins, just one table where each line serves one unique test.

So my question would be, does anybody know why my MySQL database stops counting rows above 699?

And, can I upload a file (php.ini or .htacces)to my server that prevents this?

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: I think you can get more accurate answers from http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you get when you perform the query through the mysql commandline tool?

Comment: When I use: 

SELECT Count(*) 
FROM  `table`

I get 699 rows

If I try to get a specific row that I know is there:

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `testid` = '1037'

I get nothing